# How to stop cursor from jumping to beginning of Databricks cell

Tags: mysql, databricks

When I am adding code to a cell in Databricks, it keeps jumping up to the beginning of a cell

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name USING csv OPTIONS ( path 'path_to_my_data', header 'true', inferSchema 'true', delimiter ',' );`

If I am typing code like the example above it will jump 3 or 4 times without rhyme or reason and is really starting to mess up my workflow. Is there anything I can do to keep it from moving?

I can't find anyone else that has bumped into the same problem or anything in the documentation (as far as I can tell). Additionally it doesn't matter if I am plugged into my peripherals, so I don't believe it could be a hardware issue. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please try in Private mode or a different browser, so it helps to understand whether its any plugin issue?

Comment: @GaneshChandrasekaran - I think that was it. I tried running DataBricks in Firefox and didn't run into the issue anymore, so I updated chrome. That seems to have solved the problem I was running into. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to know, switching to another browser / updating chrome worked.

When you get time, please accept the answer, so it helps others.